# Page_PreLoad() event is triggered before link button click event when I click on a link button

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm listing folders and files in drive E, I'm using a hidden field to keep the path, I created some link buttons representing folders, they are created programmatically on Page_PreLoad() event:

```
    protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfPath.Value))
        {
            path = "E:\\" + hdfPath.Value;
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        }
        else
        {
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories("E:\\");
            files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
        {
           LinkButton lkbLink = new LinkButton();
           lkbLink.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
           void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfPath.Value))
                hdfPath.Value = folderName;
              else
                hdfPath.Value += "\\" + folderName;
           }
        }
    }
```

When I click in whichever link button, first of all Page_PreLoad() event is triggered then btn_Click() event, while I expected btn_Click() to be fired first. In that case the related value on hidden field belongs to the value of one step before.

Is something wrong with the ASP.Net life cycle I chose?

How can I make it immediately set the hidden filed value when user clicks on the link button so that the (correct) current value on hidden field be taken?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the lifecycle and you can not choose a lifecycle either :)
The PreLoad-Event of the page is always before the control-events.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v%3Dvs.100)) will give you a detailed overview over the lifecycle in asp.net.

It's a little complicated in your case:

1. you need to add some buttons dynamically and attach event handlers to them - this has to be done on every postback, else the button-handlers won't be triggered.
2. Then in your handler you need to delete these before added buttons again and add the new ones according to the new path.

To achieve this, make a method from your code, e.g:

```
    private void InitButtons()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfPath.Value))
        {
            path = "E:\\" + hdfPath.Value;
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        }
        else
        {
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories("E:\\");
            files = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
        {
           LinkButton lkbLink = new LinkButton();
           lkbLink.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
           void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
              if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hdfPath.Value))
                hdfPath.Value = folderName;
              else
                hdfPath.Value += "\\" + folderName;
              // remove the old buttons here, if you need to
              // RemoveOldButtons();
              // call the Init-Buttons-Function again
              InitButtons();
           }
        }
    }
```

Call this method from your button event-handlers as shown above and again in your load-event-handler:

```
    protected void Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitButtons();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the solution is not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks, but it still worked every other time, so I applied ajax instead.